# Http post over a captcha protected jsp page using curl

Tags: php, curl, http-post, captcha

Hello Im trying to make an Http post over a jsp page using curl. but it's not working.
this is the php code I'm trying.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$captcha = $_POST['answer'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/post_comments.jsp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
"post_id=123&body=blabla&title=blabla&name=blablabla8&captcha=$captcha");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo $result;

}else {

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<img src="http://example.com/captcha.jsp" /> <input name="answer" />
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>

</form>

<?php
}

?>
```

Anybody please guide to correct it.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are made to be navigated by humans, thats why you might miss many things... Like cookies or session data. Your best bet is to make a valid request to that page and copy all the requests made. You can do it in firefox/firebug for example, or wireshark.

In short: you are probably missing cookies, emulate them

Comment: thanks.   
yes. http://example.com/captcha.jsp stores a session data. but how can i emulate them? im a newb here